# Can all views within an activity be assumed to have same Context?

Tags: android, view, android-context

I have noticed with Views in android that sometimes `getContext()` returns the containing activity, whilst other times it returns the application.

For the purposes of cleaning up pending remote image loads (which I am loading via an external load manager class), can I safely assume that all views on a particular Activity will share the same context? I was thinking of passing the activity object to cleanup and removing all views with a context matching that activity. I am sure it will depend on a few things to do with the way the views were created, just wondering what those are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually works very well in my testing. Essentially the Context passed to the layout inflater or view constructor will be the context of the view throughout its lifetime (makes sense). The only time these will mismatch is if you use different contexts (such as the application context) to inflate some parts of your layout... the context for views inflated via the activity's setContentView() will have the Activity set as theirs.